# automate http expires

Tags: javascript, http

I have a webapp written in PHP and i generate the headers with header() function.

The problem is that when I'm making changes to the javascript code of my app, on clients side, the old javascript will not be executed because is cached to the clients browsers.

How can I automate the process of header expiration? I assume that is has to be a better way than modifying that function each time I modify the javascript code.

Comment: Is this a problem in production or at development time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only bullet-proof solution is to change filenames of server-side resources:

From: Yahoo's [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires):

> Keep in mind, if you use a far future Expires header **you have to change the component's filename whenever the component changes**. At Yahoo! we often make this step part of the build process: a version number is embedded in the component's filename[...]

Of course this process must be automated. We are appending JavaScript file contents hash into file name.

Answer (score 1):

Change the URI to the script with each release.

This can be done by adding a query string. You can automate this by, for example, taking the revision number from  your version control system and inserting it into your template.

This will allow you to have long expiry times (for optimal caching) and still get fresh JavaScript each time a new release is published (so long as the HTML document isn't loaded from the cache (but they tend to have short cache times compared to JS)).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to version javascript files is to include a version number in their filename.  When you rev the code, you bump the version number and then you rev any web pages that include the JS file to refer to the new filename.  You then only need to expire the web pages themselves and they will automatically refer to the new JS files.  The JS files can have very long expiration (months or years) so you get maximum caching benefit for them.

This also ensures that you get a consistent set of JS files.

This is how jQuery does it with versioning.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide much detail only the general pointer:

Usually you can configure the `Expires` and other header params in the webserver - either globally and/or per "folder" etc.

You can make the JS file expire for example after 1 hour... this way you would know that 1 hour after a change all clients will be using the new JS file...

IF you need the change to take effect immediately even for clients currently active the header won't help much - you would have to do some AJAX magic...